# How to map string literals to types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, reflection, scripting

I'm writing a small 2D game and I'm currently adding scripting capabilities to it (using Lua or Python), and I stumbled on this problem (which I think will lead me to implement some kind of reflection system for my game):

I'm using the Entity Component System pattern, and the definition for an entity is provided by a script (a Lua table or a Python dict), so whenever I want to construct an entity I run the script:

```
player = {
     transformComponent = { 
            position = {1.0, 2.0, 0.0},
            scale = {1.0, 2.0, 1.0}
     },
     spriteComponent = {
            fileName = 'imageFile.png',
            numRows = 4,
            numCols = 6
     }
}
```

and so on.
In an EntityFactory I have a map of EntityFactoryFunctions, keyed by the name of the entity (e.g. 'Player'), and I call them when I need to construct such named entity.

Now, each factory function will read the table (dict) of the entity and get all the names of the components it needs to add to the entity.

```
Entity *CreateEntity(const std::string entityType) // table / dictionary name in script
{
    Entity *newEntity = Scene::GetInstance().AddEntity();
        
    return mEntityFactories[entityType](newEntity);
}

typedef Entity *(*EntityFactoryFunction)(Entity*);
std::map<std::string, EntityFactoryFunction> mEntityFactories;
```

Problem is, my ECS uses a function of the type enity.AddComponent<COMPONENT_TYPE>():

```
Entity *PlayerFactory(Entity *entity)
{
    // read components from Lua table / Python dictionary
    // get strings of components' names and store them into vector
    Vector<std::string> componentNames;

    // create components and add to entity
    for (const auto &componentName : componentNames)
    {
        Component *component = mComponentFactories[componentName](/* pass a reference to component table / dictionary */);
        entity->AddComponent<......>(component);  // I must know the component type
    }

    return entity;
}
```

How can I get the name of the component to pass to the function template? Do I need some kind of reflection system?

Comment: There is no reflection in C++, so, yes, you will have to implement it yourself. There's nothing in C++ that will do it for you.

Comment: even if I implement some kind of reflection system, how can I get the type of an object from a string that corresponds to its name?

Comment: Maybe C++ is the wrong tool here since once compiled most of that information is *gone*. In C++ there's a whole coding philosophy built up around operating without reflection.

Comment: "How can I get the type of an object from a string that corresponds to its name?" -- Write a Factory Method.

Comment: @Luca it all depends on the version of cpp. In cpp20 it is pretty easy to do. In earlier versions mapping string to type is kinda hack

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't need to create on object based on its string representation, I need to get an actual type from that string (to pass as a template argument). As I understand it, using a factory method I should provide an if..else if... for each case (component), which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: There is no alternative. If not a bunch of if/else statement, then a map of factory methods, this really accomplishes the same thing. The bottom line is that there is nothing in C++ that takes a name and gives you type -- with the same name or other name. C++ is a strongly-typed language. All types of all objects must be fully defined at compile time. Therefore, if a type must be selected at run time this can only be done by enumerating which type corresponding with which name, one by one (or via a map, or whatever).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, I know that C++ offers no tools for introspection (RTTI aside), my question is about how to implement one myself

Comment: Which part of "here's a list of class names, and here's a factory that creates each class in the list, or does something else with it" you're unclear about, and what is your ***specific*** question regarding this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few approaches to your problem.

1. Different types of components are not different C++ types.

In this case, your components are just bundles of properties.  Code looks at which bundles you have and behaves differently.

2. You have a fixed set of component types in C++.

Here, the scripts name kinds of components.  These are C++ types.  The mapping, between name of the component and the type, is stored in C++.  The association might be as simple as a hard coded switch statement or two.

3. You have a dynamic st of component types in C++.

In order to add more component types you can load another dynamic library, which registers the new component type and the association between the component name and the type.

4. Something crazier.

Like, you ship C++ compiler that builds component types on the fly and dynamically loads them.  Or, you write your own language, which your C++ code is really just an interpreter for.

---

I'll rule out #4.

Now, in case #1, you have nothing to do.

In case number 2/3 you still need to map that string to a type.

The simplest #2 based approach is a bunch of hard coded switch statements that take your type string and write custom code that deals with the concrete type.  This is fast, but doesn't scale well.  This is solution (a).

Another step would be to abstract the switch statement and let it be used in multiple spots.  Call this solution (b).

Another option would be to treat the entire *type* as an object itself; you write a metaclass that describes what your classes are like, and build a map from your string to the metaclass.  The metaclass itself is the same type for all of your classes.  Call this solution (c).

I think (a) is easy, if boring.  You literally do a

```
if (componentName=="bob") {
  /* code assuming the type is Bob */
} else if (componentName=="blue") {
  ...
```

An example of (b):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t = typename T::type;
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag={};

template<class...Ts>
using tags_t = std::variant<tag_t<Ts>...>;

namespace Components{
  using ComponentTag = tags_t<Transform, Sprite, Physics>;
  ComponentTag GetTagFromName(std::string_view str) {
    if(str=="transformComponent") return tag<Transform>;
    if(str=="spriteComponent") return tag<Sprite>;
    // ...
  }
}
```

now we get:

```
// create components and add to entity
for (const auto &componentName : componentNames)
{
    Component *component = mComponentFactories[componentName](/* pass a reference to component table / dictionary */);
    auto tag = Components::GetTagFromName(componentName);
    std::visit([&](auto tag) {
      using Type = type_t<decltype(tag)>;
      entity->AddComponent<Type>(component);  // I must know the component type
    }, tag);
}
```

in the final version (c), we can do:

```
for (const auto &componentName : componentNames)
{
    IMetaComponent* meta = mComponentMetaFactory[componentName];
    Component *component = meta->Create(/* pass a reference to component table / dictionary */);
    meta->Add(entity, component);
}
```

here, the `IMetaComponent` gets virtual methods for each operation that needs to be done on components that needs to know the type.

MetaComponent implementations themselves could be written using a template for 90%+ of its code, but it has a base `IMetaComponent` that isn't a template.

(c) has many advantages, like the ability to extend, and the ability to unit test the `MetaComponent`s themselves.

(b) has the advantage that once set up, you just write code that does the thing where you need it to be done.  It does require either [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) to get a good variant and lambda syntax to work with.

Comment: Ok, I think I need some time to read it through and understand, since some stuff is a bit over my head. Food for thought, thanks.

Comment: @Luca Basically, C++ doesn't have reflection, but you can implement it with some manual work.  And here are 3 ways.  The first you know.